# Paho MQTT: Error during autorun

Tags: boot, amazon, mqtt

I am trying to run a Python script on startup.

I followed [this guide from Instructibles on setting up a cron job](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/).

It returns the following error in the logs:

```
File "IoTTest.py", line 58, in <module>
client.connect("Axxxxxxxxxx.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", xxxx, xx)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 612, in connect
return self.reconnect()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/paho/mqtt/client.py", line 734, in reconnect
sock = socket.create_connection((self._host, self._port), source_address=(self._bind_address, 0))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 553, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Basically, I want to send a message to AWS IoT using Python:

```py
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
  if rc == 0 :
    print("CONNECTED TO AWS IoT")
    client.subscribe("$aws/things/XXXXX/shadow/update/accepted")
     ....
    return True

  else :
    client.disconnect() 
    return False

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
  ....

client = mqtt.Client(client_id="Test")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.tls_set(ca_certs='./certs/root-CA.crt', certfile='./certs/xxxx-certificate.pem.crt', keyfile='./certs/xxxx-private.pem.key', tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
client.tls_insecure_set(True)
client.connect("Axxxxxxxxxx.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com", xxxx, xx)  ===> log showed error here !
client.loop_forever()
```

Note: I can run this python script successfully with direct command:

```
python IoTTest.py
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your code is running before the network is actually ready, so when trying to resolve the URL, things go horribly wrong and your script crashes.

Cron provides [no real promises](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/cron/crontab.5.en.html) about when `@reboot` scripts run:

> Please note that startup, as far as @reboot is concerned, is the time when the cron(8) daemon startup. In particular, it may be before some system daemons, or other facilities, were startup. This is due to the boot order sequence of the machine.

If you are using a Raspbian version after or including Jessie (i.e. Jessie or Stretch as of 2017), you can take advantage of `systemd`, which gives you much more control.

Let's create a new service file at `/etc/systemd/system/iottest.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start IoTTest
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/yourusername/IoTTest.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You'll probably need to create that file with root privileges. Once done, save that, disable your cron job and run:

```
systemctl enable iottest.service
```

Then, reboot, and you're done!

**However**, Debian Jessie apparently has some issues with [`network-online.target`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209832/debian-systemd-network-online-target-not-working); it may be necessary to work around this as described in the link.

Comment: Hi Aurora0001, your suggestion is very interesting, however it seems not working. I followed your step, ran: sudo systemctl enable iottest.service. It returns: Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/iottest.service to /etc/systemd/system/iottest.service. After rebooting the RPi, it doesn't send any msg to AWS ioT

Comment: @francophong Any interesting output from `journalctl -u iottest.service` that might give us a clue what's happening?

Comment: @ Aurora0001, I tried, it returns: No journal files were found. Does it mean the service didn't start or something wrong ?

Comment: @francophong Did you run that as root (`sudo journalctl -u iottest.service`)? I forgot to mention that, sorry.

Comment: yes, it did return some errors: [/etc/systemd/system/iottest.service:8] Executable path is not absolute, ignoring: python /home/pi/Test/IoTTest.py

iottest.service lacks both ExecStart= and ExecStop= setting. Refusing.

Comment: @francophong Oh... My fault again (long time since I've written a systemd script!). I've edited my `/etc/systemd/system/iottest.service` example; this time, it should work, hopefully (just replace `python` with `/usr/bin/python` on the line `ExecStart`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65350/discussion-between-franco-phong-and-aurora0001).

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this error: as Aurora0001 mentioned, script ran before network is ready. Although his solution is not working, but I found an workaround for it.

In launcher.sh, I added a delay about 10 secs(you need check it depend on RPi) . That's it, and it works fine.

```
sleep 10s
cd /
cd home/pi
sudo python IoTTest.py
cd /
```